# jquery image slide procedure faulty in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, image, slideshow

Where did I go wrong? IE reports a problem while everything else seems to be just fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  menu = $('#menu > ul > li');
  image = $('#image > ul > li > div');
  menu.each(function(idx) {
    this.slide = image[idx];
    }).hover(
    function() {
      menu.removeClass('active');
      image.removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $(this.slide).addClass('active');
    });
  });
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: IE8 64 bit no error message at all, just doesnt work. Following in IE8 32-bit:

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 27 points to menu = $(... etc...) above
Char: 7
Code: 0

When parsing through Lint/FF, I get a notification that I've passed a function() on hover, but this does not seem to disturb the actual procedure in FF.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use `.hover()`! Instead you should use `.mouseenter()` or `.mouseover()`. I don't trust much that line: `this.slide = image[idx];` it should be fine but i would prefer using `this.slide = image.eq(idx)[0];` instead.

Comment: You should delete this answer while you still have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: Replacing to the suggested has no effect, I am afraid. Eventhough I agree .mouseenter() might be a more appropriate fx in this case.